# form button to open up new URL in same window

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a button at the bottom of a form that when is pressed I would like to open up a new URL in the same window. Right now with the code I have it opens up a new window /tab. If I put ,"_self" after the url, the button breaks completely. Here is my code

```
 $(".study-btn").click(function(){
    if(questionCounter == 3)
    {
        window.open("http://www.google.com");
        // I tried this but breaks completely
        window.open("http://www.google.com", "_self");
    }
    else
    {
        window.open("http://http://www.amazon.com");
    }

});
```

The question counter is just to me to figure out which of the form questions have been answered YES or NO.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Open a URL in a new tab using JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4907843/open-a-url-in-a-new-tab-using-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

Using this should work to open a website in a new tab in the same window:

```
window.open('www.google.com','_target');
```

If you just want to change the current page, use:

```
location = 'http://www.google.com';
```

Comment: This still opens up a new tab

Comment: This should open in a new tab in the same window. Is that not what you want? My edit shows how to change the current url...

Comment: When I try to use the location method the url is changed to this      http://www.google.com?radio=Yes&radio=Yes&radio=Yes

Comment: what url are you using?

Comment: The whole URL is there

Comment: same result, opens up URL in new window / tab

Answer (score 0):

This should work if you want to stay in the same window.  window.open AFAIK usually opens a new "pop-up" window, which you don't need if you want to stay in the current window.

```
$(".study-btn").click(function(){
    if(questionCounter == 3)
    {
        location.href="http://www.google.com";
    }
    else
    {
        location.href="http://http://www.amazon.com";
    }
});
```

Comment: this seems to just reload the page with the answers from the form in the URL

Comment: @icekomo can you set up a simple JsFiddle to show what you have now and what you wish to accomplish?  Looks like you may need to set your FORM method to POST if you're seeing values in the URL.